# bundle.getParcelable("givenKey"); NOT returning the object set using putParcelable("givenKey")

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android programming.
          I am NOT able to get the data using getParcelable() in one Activity that is set using putParcelable in my previousActivity.

My MainActivity.java :-

```
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TheatresListForMovie.class);                
            Bundle b =new Bundle();
            HashMap cast_N_crewHashMap=new HashMap();
            cast_N_crewHashMap.put("Banner", "Suresh Productions");
            cast_N_crewHashMap.put("Directed by","Trivikram Srinivas");
            cast_N_crewHashMap.put("Story","Trivikram Srinivas");
            cast_N_crewHashMap.put("Screenplay","Trivikram Srinivas");
            cast_N_crewHashMap.put("Music","DeviSri Prasad");
            cast_N_crewHashMap.put("Release Year","2000");
            Movie m1 = new Movie("0-000-001","1st Movie","Telugu",5.0f,"U","Family\
            Drama",cast_N_crewHashMap);
            Log.d("cast_N_crewHashMap ",cast_N_crewHashMap.toString());
            b.putParcelable("MovieData", m1);
            i.putExtras(b);
            Log.d("From Main Activity, After Preparing Intent :\
            ",i.getExtras().toString());                
            startActivity(i);
```

---

### And , My TheatresListForMovie.java :-

```
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            Set bundleSet=bundle.keySet();
            Iterator bundleIterator=bundleSet.iterator();
        while(bundleIterator.hasNext()){
    String thisBundle=(String) bundleIterator.next();
    Object thisValue=bundle.get(thisBundle);
    Log.d("Bundle has these : ",thisBundle);
    Log.d("And : ",String.valueOf(thisValue));
        }
        Log.d("From TheatresListForMovie :Bundle= ",bundle.toString());
        Movie m1 = new Movie();
        m1=bundle.getParcelable("MovieData");
        Log.d("From TheatresListForMovie:m1=",String.valueOf(m1));
        Log.d("From TheatresListForMovie:m1.getMovieId()=",m1.getMovieId());
        Log.d("From TheatresListForMovie :Bundle= ",b.toString());
        String str="Movie ID : "+m1.getMovieId() + "\n";
        str+="Movie Name : "+m1.getMovieName()+"\n";
            str+="Language : "+m1.getLanguage()+"\n";
            str+="User Rating : "+m1.getUserRating()+"\n";
        str+="Censor Rating : "+m1.getCensorRating()+"\n";
        str+="Genre : "+m1.getGenre()+"\n";
         Log.d("From TheatresListForMovie :str= ",str);
```

---

My Log Trace shows:-

```
                " D/From Movie :Movie=(1455): 0-000-001
                 D/From Movie :Movie=(1455): 1st Movie
                 D/From Movie :Movie=(1455): Telugu
                 D/From Movie :Movie=(1455): 5.0
                 D/From Movie :Movie=(1455): U
                 D/From Movie :Movie=(1455): Family Drama
                 D/From Movie :Movie=(1455): {Story=Trivikram Srinivas,\
                    Music=DeviSri Prasad, Directed by=Trivikram Srinivas, Banner=Suresh \  
                   Productions, Screenplay=Trivikram Srinivas, Release Year=2000}
                 D/cast_N_crewHashMap(1455): {Music=DeviSri Prasad,\  
                    Story=Trivikram Srinivas, Directed by=Trivikram Srinivas, Banner=Suresh \
                    Productions, Screenplay=Trivikram Srinivas, Release Year=2000}
                 D/From Main Activity, After Preparing Intent :(1455):  \
                    Bundle[{MovieData=sgr.gvb.movieticketsapp.Movie@5282c21c}]
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : movieId =(1455): 0-000-001
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : movieName =(1455): 1st Movie
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : language =(1455): Telugu
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : userRating =(1455): 5.0
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : censorRating =(1455): U
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : genre =(1455): Family Drama
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : key =(1455): Story
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : val =(1455): Trivikram Srinivas
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : key =(1455): Music
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : val =(1455): DeviSri Prasad
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : key =(1455): Directed by
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : val =(1455): Trivikram Srinivas
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : key =(1455): Banner
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : val =(1455): Suresh Productions
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : key =(1455): Screenplay
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : val =(1455): Trivikram Srinivas
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : key =(1455): Release Year
                 D/Movie : writing To dest : val =(1455): 2000
                 W/EGL_genymotion(1455): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : movieId =(1455): 0-000-001
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : movieName =(1455): 1st Movie
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : language =(1455): Telugu
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : userRating =(1455): 5.0
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : censorRating =(1455): U
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : genre =(1455): Family Drama
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : key =(1455): Release Year
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : value=(1455): 2000
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : key =(1455): Directed by
                 D/Movie : Reading From Source : value=(1455): Trivikram \
                                                Srinivas
                D/Movie : Reading From Source : key =(1455): Music
                D/Movie : Reading From Source : value=(1455): DeviSri Prasad
                D/Movie : Reading From Source : key =(1455): Story
               D/Movie : Reading From Source : value=(1455): Trivikram \
               Srinivas
                D/Movie : Reading From Source : key =(1455): Screenplay
                D/Movie : Reading From Source : value=(1455): Trivikram \
               Srinivas
               D/Movie : Reading From Source : key =(1455): Banner
               D/Movie : Reading From Source : value=(1455): Suresh \
              Productions
               D/Bundle has these :(1455): MovieData
              D/And :(1455): sgr.gvb.movieticketsapp.Movie@54b9da48
               D/From TheatresListForMovie :Bundle=(1455):     \
                    Bundle[{MovieData=sgr.gvb.movieticketsapp.Movie@54b9da48}]
                D/From TheatresListForMovie:m1=(1455):\
                sgr.gvb.movieticketsapp.Movie@54b9da48
               D/From TheatresListForMovie:m1.getMovieId()=(1455): No_Movie
                D/From TheatresListForMovie :str=(1455): Movie ID : No_Movie
               D/From TheatresListForMovie :str=(1455): Movie Name : No_Movie
               D/From TheatresListForMovie :str=(1455): Language : 
               DefaultLanguage
```

### ...................

That is, the data appears fine in the second activity.
However, only when I use getParcelable , the data that is collected for the same key, appears to be giving problem.

### Please help . Thanks in advance...

My Movie.java File is :
                /**
                 * 
                */
                package sgr.gvb.movieticketsapp;

```
            import java.util.HashMap;
            import java.util.Iterator;
            import java.util.Map;
            import java.util.Map.Entry;
            import java.util.Set;

            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.os.Parcel;
            import android.os.Parcelable;
            import android.util.Log;

            /**
             * @author GVBhaskar
             *
             */
            public class Movie implements Parcelable {

                /* (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see android.os.Parcelable#describeContents()
                 */
                String movieId;
                String movieName;
                String language;
                float userRating;
                String censorRating;
                String genre;
                HashMap cast_N_crew=new HashMap();


                public String getMovieId(){
                    return "No_Movie";
                }

                public void setMovieId(String newMovieId){
                    movieId=newMovieId;
                }

                public String getMovieName(){
                    return "No_Movie";
                }

                public void setMovieName(String newMovieName){
                    movieName=newMovieName;
                }

                public String getLanguage(){
                    return "DefaultLanguage";
                }

                public void setLanguage(String newLanguage){
                    language=newLanguage;
                }

                public float getUserRating(){
                    return 0.0f;
                }

                public void setUserRating(float newUserRating){
                    userRating=newUserRating;
                }

                public String getCensorRating(){
                    return "DefaultCensorRating";
                }

                public void setCensorRating(String newCensorRating){
                    censorRating=newCensorRating;
                }

                public String getGenre(){
                    return "Default Genre";
                }

                public void setGenre(String newGenre){
                    genre=newGenre;
                }

                public HashMap getCastNCrew(){
                    return new HashMap();
                }

                public void setCastNCrew(HashMap newCast_N_Crew){
                    Set currentMember=cast_N_crew.keySet();
                    Iterator currentMemberIterator=currentMember.iterator();
                    Set newMember=newCast_N_Crew.keySet();
                    Iterator newMemberIterator=newMember.iterator();
                    while(currentMemberIterator.hasNext()){
                        String thisRole=(String)currentMemberIterator.next();
                        if(newCast_N_Crew.containsKey(thisRole)){
                            cast_N_crew.put(thisRole, newCast_N_Crew.get(thisRole));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cast_N_crew.remove(thisRole);
                        }
                    }
                    while(newMemberIterator.hasNext()){
                        String newRole=(String)newMemberIterator.next();
                        if(!cast_N_crew.containsKey(newRole)){
                            cast_N_crew.put(newRole, newCast_N_Crew.get(newRole));
                        }
                    }
                }

                public Movie(String thisMovieId,String thisMovieName,String thisMovieLanguage,
                        float thisMovieUserRating,String thisMovieCensorRating,
                        String thisMovieGenre,HashMap thisMovieCast_N_Crew){
                    movieId=thisMovieId;
                    movieName=thisMovieName;
                    language=thisMovieLanguage;
                    userRating=thisMovieUserRating;
                    censorRating=thisMovieCensorRating;
                    genre=thisMovieGenre;
                    cast_N_crew=(HashMap) thisMovieCast_N_Crew.clone();
                    Log.d("From Movie :Movie= ",movieId+"\n"+movieName+"\n"+language+"\n"+String.valueOf(userRating)+"\n"+censorRating+"\n"+genre+"\n"+String.valueOf(cast_N_crew));
                }

                public Movie(Parcel source) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    cast_N_crew=new HashMap();
                    movieId=source.readString();
                     Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : movieId =",movieId);

                    movieName=source.readString();
                     Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : movieName =",movieName);

                    language=source.readString();
                     Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : language =",language);

                    userRating=source.readFloat();
                     Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : userRating =",String.valueOf(userRating));

                    censorRating=source.readString();
                     Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : censorRating =",censorRating);

                    genre=source.readString();
                     Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : genre =",genre);

                    final Bundle cast_N_crewBundle=source.readBundle();
                    final Iterator<String> iter = cast_N_crewBundle.keySet().iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        final String key =iter.next();
                        Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : key =",key);
                        Object value=cast_N_crewBundle.get(key);
                        Log.d("Movie : Reading From Source : value=",(String)value);
                        cast_N_crew.put(key, value);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int describeContents() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return 0;
                }
                public Movie(){

                }

                /* (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see android.os.Parcelable#writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int)
                 */
                @Override
                public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : movieId =",movieId);

                    dest.writeString(movieId);
                     Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : movieName =",movieName);

                    dest.writeString(movieName);
                     Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : language =",language);

                    dest.writeString(language);
                     Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : userRating =",String.valueOf(userRating));

                    dest.writeFloat(userRating);
                     Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : censorRating =",censorRating);

                    dest.writeString(censorRating);
                     Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : genre =",genre);

                    dest.writeString(genre);

                    final Bundle cast_N_crewBundle=new Bundle();
                    final Iterator <Entry<String,String>> iter=cast_N_crew.entrySet().iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        final Entry<String, String>  entry =iter.next();
                        String key=entry.getKey();
                        String val=entry.getValue();
                        Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : key =",key);
                        Log.d("Movie : writing To dest : val =",val);

                        cast_N_crewBundle.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                    dest.writeBundle(cast_N_crewBundle);
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

                    @Override
                    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return new Movie(source);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return new Movie[size];
                    }
                };
```

### }

Thanks,
Bhaskar.

Comment: you should add that class code to your post here, not a users answer.

Comment: Is your code in `Movie` class a testing/debug one?  It always return "Default XXX " in its `getter` method.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you instantiating `Movie`? No need for that:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Movie m1 = bundle.getParcelable("MovieData");
```

Make sure that `Movie` implements Parcelable properly! There's a helper website for that: http://www.parcelabler.com

If you want to be save you can [check if the key exists](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#containsKey%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if (bundle.containsKey("MovieData")) {...}
```

Comment: Yes, I ensured...still, not getting

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `Movie` class.  It may not implement the `Parcelable` interface correctly.

Comment: It is implementing parcelable interface properly.

Comment: I don’t think so :) Even tho this is from 2014.